# error in scipy interp1d

Tags: python, scipy

I do not understand the result reported by interp1d. I receive NAN where I should receive numbers.

```
In [131]: bb
Out[131]: 
array([ 0.        ,  1.80286595,  1.87443683,  2.70410611,  3.02764722,
        3.11305985,  3.11534355,  3.18695351,  3.20693444])

In [132]: alphas1
Out[134]: 
array([  3.80918778e+00,   2.06547222e+00,   1.99234191e+00,
         7.55942418e-01,   2.56971574e-01,   1.05144676e-01,
         9.30852046e-02,   1.52574183e-02,   1.23664407e-07])

In [135]: bb.shape
Out[135]: (9,)

In [136]: alphas1.shape
Out[140]: (9,)

In [141]: pol = interp1d(alphas1, bb, bounds_error=False)

In [149]: pol(pol.x)
Out[149]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]) # I was expecting to receive nan only at the borders.
```

Comment: Which version? Gives the right answer of `np.array([ 3.20693444,  3.18695351,  ...` in `scipy 0.14.0` `numpy 1.8.1`

Comment: In [25]: np.version.version
Out[29]: '1.8.1'

In [30]: scipy.version.version
Out[44]: '0.13.3'

Comment: Update `scipy` it might go away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem can be seen, I think, if you examine the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py) for the `interp1d` class, namely the `_check_bounds` method:

```
def _check_bounds(self, x_new):

    ...

    below_bounds = x_new < self.x[0]
    above_bounds = x_new > self.x[-1]

    # !! Could provide more information about which values are out of bounds
    if self.bounds_error and below_bounds.any():
        raise ValueError("A value in x_new is below the interpolation "
            "range.")
    if self.bounds_error and above_bounds.any():
        raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
            "range.")
```

The method checks if the value of x you are trying to put in is less than `self.x[0]`, the first element of `x` (`alphas1` in your case). Since `alphas1[0]` is the *largest* element of your `x` list, every element thereafter will be "out of range," i.e. smaller than the first element.

A way around this would be to reverse your `x` and `y` lists:

```
bb = bb[::-1]
alphas1 = alphas[::-1]
pol = interp1d(alphas1, bb, bounds_error=False)
```

Now `alphas1` will be increasing, as scipy expects, and `pol(pol.x)` will return `bb` as expected (reversed now).